# Wordpress permalink structure with custom taxonomy and without base-name

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, permalinks

I want to create the following permalink structure

custom post type: `resources`
custom taxonomy: `resources-category` (e.g. Sales, Business, ...)

how can I get this structure: `url.com/%resources-category%/detail-slug`

e.g.
`url.com/sales/how-to-sale`
`url.com/business/how-to-something`

What I get until now is, that I can open this urls, but they are automatically redirected to my custom post type `resources` slug
e.g.
`url.com/sales/how-to-sale` redirects to `url.com/resources/how-to-sale`

I registered the post type:

```
    function registerTypeResources () {
        register_post_type('resources',
            array(
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __('Resources'),
                    'singular_name' => __('Resources')
                ),
                'public' => true,
                'has_archive' => false,
                'supports' => array('title', 'thumbnail', 'editor'),
                'show_in_rest' => true,
            )
        );
    }

    add_action('init', 'registerTypeResources');
```

I've added the taxonomy:

```
    add_action('init', 'registerRessourcesTaxonomy', 0);
    
    function registerRessourcesTaxonomy () {
        register_taxonomy(
            'resources-category',
            'resources',
            array(
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __('Categories'),
                    'add_new_item' => __('Add new category'),
                    'new_item_name' => __('New category ')
                ),
                'show_in_rest' => true,
                'show_ui' => true,
                'show_tagcloud' => false,
                'hierarchical' => true
            )
        );
    
    }
```

I added a rewrite:

```
    add_action('init', function () {
        add_rewrite_rule('sales/(.+)/?$', 'index.php?resources=$matches[1]', 'bottom');
        add_rewrite_rule('business/(.+)/?$', 'index.php?resources=$matches[1]', 'bottom');
    });
```

How can I disable the redirect to resources?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer for my self. Maybe someone else needs this solution, too.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/328279/custom-permalink-structure-custom-taxonomy-post-name-without-cpt-slug